# I want to convert string "var=02-24-2013 12:40:00.0 into a java script date object?

Tags: javascript

```
<span id="datePickerSpan${email.id}">
<g:formatDate date="${scheduleDate}" format="dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm"/>
</span>
<input type="text" id="datePicker${email.id}" style="display:none"/>
<span onclick="openDateTimePicker('${email.id}')"></span>    

<g:javascript>

    var str='${scheduleDate}';//2013-02-2412:40:00.0
    str = str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*$/g, '$1');
    alert("Str is=> "+str);//2013-02-24 12:40:00
    var date2=new Date(str);
    alert(" yy dd mm alert"+date2);//invalid date object
    str = str.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g, '$2-$3-$1');
    alert("now new Str is =>"+str);//02-24-2013 12:40:00.0
    var date=new Date(str);
    alert("now str date is =>"+date);//invalid date object
    var date1=new Date();
alert("java script date is =>"+date1);//Wed Feb 13 2013 11:16:55 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
    $('#datePicker${email.id}').datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      minDateTime: new Date(),
      maxDateTime:null,
      defaultDate:new Date(),
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: requestPath + "/images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect : function(dateText,obj){
            saveRescheduleDate(${email.id},dateText);
            }
     });
 </g:javascript>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) is created with new Date().:

```
new Date("02-24-2013 12:40:00.0");
```

Comment: i've taken dat in str and when i try to pass in date  obje i i got invalid date object  as alert

Comment: and also luk d alert of date2 and date 1 var

Comment: there is no space between date and time `format="dd-MM-yyyyHH:mm"`, try to change it to `format="dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"`

Comment: @ hendy the problem is same.........var str='${scheduleDate}';//2013-02-2412:40:00.0

str = str.replace(/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*$/g, '$1');

 alert("Str is=> "+str);//2013-02-24 12:40:00

str = str.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/g, '$2-$3-$1');

 alert("now new Str is =>"+str);//02-24-2013 12:40:00

var date=new Date(str);

alert("now str date is =>"+date);//invalid date object

Answer (score 0):

you can declare Date object like this

```
var dt= new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")
```

try this link for more reference

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp

Comment: if a pass may current date var str=2013-02-24 12:40:00.0.........
                                 var dateStr=Date.parse(str);...........
                                          alert(dateStr);...Nan is output

Comment: var str='2013-02-24 12:40:00';
    var dateStr=new Date(str.replace('-','/'));
    alert(dateStr); you cannot use "-" in the string